# How to prevent fancybox onClosed event

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have fancybox popup iframe and i am submitting the parent form on onClosed, its shown below

```
'onClosed'          : function() {
        parent.document.forms[0].submit();
 }
```

And i have a form inside popup iframe, i want the onClosed event to be executed only when the form is submitted, but not clicking on close button, currently, the onClosed is getting executed in both the conditions, how to prevent the onClosed actions not to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `onClosed` option and add this attribute to the `form` **tag** (not the `submit` button) inside fancybox:

```
onsubmit="javascript:parent.document.forms[0].submit();jQuery.fancybox.close();"
```

if the visitor closes fancybox using the `close` button, then the form won't be submitted.

I hope you were clear when you said "*i have a form inside popup iframe*" because not necessarily all the content inside of fancybox is an `iframe`.

are you opening fancybox with the option `"type":"iframe"` ? 
if so, then the `onsubmit` attribute should look like:

```
onsubmit="javascript:parent.parent.document.forms[0].submit();parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();"
```

Comment: I am getting this error on server not localy  "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://mysite/report/report.php from frame with URL http://mysite/report/edit-details.php. Domains, protocols and ports must match"

Comment: I can hardly imagine that this error is associated to fancybox script but other restrictions like cross-domain policies or hosting restrictions or else. In this case I would rather use relative paths over absolute paths.